# Paypal rejected reference transaction feature

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

PayPal rejected reference transactions feature for client account. They told us we can still use recurring transactions but not reference transactions feature.

Whole project coding is did using reference transaction with first creating billing agreement id and use that billing id for future transactions.

What will be the options here?

Answer (score 0):

For unique transaction id for recurring payment try to use parameters PROFILEID in combination with PROFILEREFERENCE